# Papa parse runs out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, papaparse

With PapaParse I'm parsing a csv file which I then add to variable dataShort and dataTotal. I am able to log both dataShort and dataTotal inside of the complete function but not below it. I suppose this happens because the function runs asynchronously.

As a result of that the following functions (both changeData and dataReady) can't run successfully since they require Papa Parse to be done with parsing. How can I make changeData(); in the function parseCSV run only when the parsing above is complete?

```js
function parseCSV(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    Papa.parse(file, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: function (results) {
            dataShort = results.data;
            dataTotal = results.data;
            console.log(results.data);
            console.log("dataShort: " + dataShort);
            console.log("dataTotal: " + dataTotal);
        }
    });
    console.log("dataShort: " + dataShort);
    console.log("dataTotal: " + dataTotal);
    
    changeData();
}



function changeData() {
    $.each(dataShort, function (index, item) {

        if (item["Items in CHILDoc"].length > 20) {
            item["Items in CHILDoc"] = item["Items in CHILDoc"].substring(0, 18) + "...";
        }
        if (item["Kwadrant onderdeel in CHILDoc"] != "Ingrijpende gebeurtenissen" && item["Waarde in CHILDoc"].length > 20) {
            item["Waarde in CHILDoc"] = item["Waarde in CHILDoc"].substring(0, 15) + "...";
        }
    })
    //            console.log(dataShort);
    //            console.log(dataTotal);
    dataReady();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about it running asynchronously. You can directly call your `changeData` function from `complete` event function. So try something like this:

```
function parseCSV(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  Papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: function(results) {
      dataTotal = results.data;
      dataShort = results.data;
      changeData(dataShort);       
    }
  });
}

function changeData(var ds) {
  $.each(ds, function(index, item) {
    if (item["Items in CHILDoc"].length > 20) {
      item["Items in CHILDoc"] = item["Items in CHILDoc"].substring(0, 18) + "...";
    }
    if (item["Kwadrant onderdeel in CHILDoc"] != "Ingrijpende gebeurtenissen" && item["Waarde in CHILDoc"].length > 20) {
      item["Waarde in CHILDoc"] = item["Waarde in CHILDoc"].substring(0, 15) + "...";
    }
  });
  dataReady();
}
```

Here, I changed the `changeData` function to accept result data and calling it from the `complete` function. <del>Note that, I remove `dataShort` and `dataTotal` variables as I did not see any use of it here but do revert it back, if you are using them further somewhere in your code.</del>

**Edit:** `dataShorts` gets modified after calling `changeData` function but `dataTotal` would still have the original result. I am assuming you are declaring both `dataShort` and `dataTotal` variables somewhere on the top.

Comment: What I would like to happen is that so the data in array dataShort gets indeed shortened by the function changeData but the array dataTotal remains unchanged. As of now, when I run the code I posted above with changeData(); placed in the complete, somehow results.data gets changed by changeData, not dataShort.

I use dataShort to add a span with text so even long data entries fit the divs I made. dataTotal is used to add titles to the shortened spans so the text can still be read.